# PHP, при выводе текста первый символ заменяется на знак вопроса

Tags: php, строки

Здравствуйте, есть простой код считывания текста из файла

```
<?php 
    $myfile = fopen("tests.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");

if ($myfile) {  
    while(!feof($myfile)) {
        $s = fgets($myfile);
        echo $s{0}.'</br>';
    }
}
?>
```

Я хочу вывести первый символ каждой строки, но первый символ первой строки выводится как �. 

Если выводить строку целиком то такой проблемы нету. 
Кодировки проверил UTF-8 стоит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так можно выбрать первый символ во многобайтных кодировках

```
echo mb_substr($s, 0, 1);
```

[image: Скрин кода, файла (откуда берется текст) и вывода в браузер]

Comment: Так вообще первый символ не выводится

Comment: Значит у вас первый символ не буква, возможно перевод строки. Суть функции в том, что она вырезает 1 символ начиная с нулевой позиции.  Можете попробовать добавить сюда кодировку - echo mb_substr($с, 0, 1, 'UTF-8');

Comment: К сожалению не всё так просто, опять же повторюсь, что если вывести не конкретный символ а всю строку $s то выведет нормально все строки включая первую с первым символом

Comment: Поиграйтесь со вторым параметром функции. Для проверки поставьте вместо единицы null, она выберет всю строку.

Comment: А как тогда объяснить, что на всех остальных строках кроме первой - первый символ строки отображает нормально, и не важно берем ли мы его функцией какой-либо или же просто обращаемся по индексу к первому символу

Comment: Если речь о моем скрине, то в файле присутствует перевод строки, который по сути тоже есть символ (см. таблицу символов ASCII). Функция отрабатывает правильно. А что из себя представляет ваш tests.txt - этого я не знаю.

Comment: Я кажется догадался. Вы когда сохраняли файл в UTF-8, то поставили метку "сохранять с BOM". Это служебная инфа, которая идет в начале файла. Пересохраните файл "без BOM" и должно все получиться.

Comment: Файл так выглядит
https://snag.gy/ZHrhvN.jpg

Comment: Да, сохранил без BOM и заработало, правда никакой метки я не ставил так как её нету в обычном блокноте (вроде бы). Но главное проблема решена, спасибо.

Comment: Позволю себе два совета. 1 не используйте блокнот. Хоть часто и говорят "пишите хоть в блокноте" - это так себе идея. Попробуйте тот же Sublime Text, Notepad++. 2 При сохранении проверяйте этот BOM. Проблема в том, что его присутствие может сильно подгадить впоследствии. Например не даст сделать header location.

Comment: Ну это понятно, я просто для быстрого редактирования использовал блокнот, ещё раз спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Все правильно, когда вы выводите всю строку "отображаются" все байты. Кириллица в UTF-8 занимает больше одного байта, mb_substr должен вывести первую букву с учетом количества байт в символе в этой кодировке (для корректной работы этой функции необходимы корректные настройки mbstring.func_overload и mbstring.internal_encoding)

Попробуйте в коде отобразить следующее:
echo(fgets($myfile,2));
или
echo(fgets($myfile,3));

Comment: Не, проблема только в первой строке, во всех остальных строках всё нормально работает, у меня есть строка и я получаю первый символ через нулевой индекс, в первом случае в первой строке не работает, в остальных работает